# Preventing Child Process Termination on Node.js Error When Executing an EXE File

Tags: node.js, http, child-process, process-management, execfile

I'm a developer working with Node.js and I've encountered an issue using the child_process module's **`execFile`** function.

When I use it to open and run an EXE file, I've noticed that if my Node.js project encounters an error, **the process started by the EXE file also terminates unexpectedly.**

Is there an alternative function or method I can use to ensure that running `./index.exe` from the terminal behaves the same way when invoked from my Node.js project, without it being affected by the Node.js process's state?

I attempted to execute the file via an HTTP request. Could this have been an issue?

```
executableRouter.post('/start-exe', async (req, res) => {
  const running = await isProcessRunning(exeFile); 
  if (running) {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ message: 'Process is already running. No action taken.' });
  }

  execFile(exeFile, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing .exe: ${error}`);
    }
  });

  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Attempting to start .exe' });
});
```